# Does Android 13 on a Pixel 6a support LE Audio or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using a Pixel 6a with Android 13.

When querying the Bluetooth adapter for LE Audio support, I get the following:

- 2MPhy supported? Yes.
- LE Audio supported? No.
- Extended Advertising supported? Yes.
- Periodic Advertising supported? Yes.

What exactly does this mean? It clearly says that LE Audio is not supported but periodic advertising is. Periodic advertising is introduced in 5.2 as part of LE Audio support. Does the above mean that I can receive LE Audio advertising (Ext and Per) but not ISO packets?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, Android 13 on a pixel 6a should support LE Audio. Most of the SW features of LE Audio have been added in Android 13 (as can be seen in this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/summary)) and hardware-wise you need a chipset with BTv5.2 (which the Pixel 6a has as can be seen [here](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7158570?sjid=150138972598447326-EU)). However, the reason you are seeing that it is not supported is because [isLeAudioSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#isLeAudioSupported()) API is being called and it is returning false, which indicates that it is in fact not supported. it is possible that this is related to LC3 support which LE Audio requires (even though [some articles indicate that LC3 was added in Tensor 2](https://www.gsmarena.com/new_pixel_7_series_to_support_bluetooth_le_audio_lc3_codec-news-55590.php) which the Pixel 6a has). In any case, your best bet is to contact Google about this as they will have the definitive answer as to why you are seeing no support on the 6a.

Answer (score 0):

While Android 13 generally support *Bluetooth LE Audio* aka. Auracast™, this is currently a development topic and must therefore first be activated in the developer menu.

I can confirm that both Pixel 6 and Pixel 7 contain the menu item, but in Pixel 6 it is greyed out. I interpret this to mean that Google has not (yet) released *Bluetooth LE Audio* for this platform.